# How to debug Fog and CarrierWave, setting remote_avatar_url to facebook profile pic causes save to fail, but no error is generated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I'm setting remote_avatar_url to 
http://graph.facebook.com/#{params[:uid]}/picture?width=512&height=512

and it causes my user.save() to fail. This worked fine a few weeks ago. I know that this URL above is actually redirected to another url by facebook, so not sure if that is the issue. Would be great if I could find out a way to debug this as no errors show up in my rails server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can view the raw fog requests by setting the `EXCON_DEBUG` environment variable to `true`.

Try executing your app from the command line as follows:

`EXCON_DEBUG=true bundle exec rails server`

Something tells me you're right, the redirect is causing problems.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to give me any more information. I had to add some code that essentially retrieved the location of the 302 redirect before I set it to remote_avatar_url. No clue on why it stopped working in the first place, but seems to be ok now.